# Correlation/p values of all combinations of all rows of two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I would like to calculate the correlation and the p value of that correlatio of each species (bac) to each of the factors (fac) in a second data frame. Both were measured at the same number of stations, but the number of bac and fac don't match.

```
bac1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
bac2 <- c(2,3,4,5,1)
bac3 <- c(4,5,1,2,3)
bac4 <- c(5,1,2,3,4)
bac <- as.data.frame(cbind(bac1, bac2, bac3, bac4 ))
colnames(bac) <- c("station1", "station2", "station3", "station4")
rownames(bac) <- c("bac1", "bac2", "bac3", "bac4", "bac5")

fac1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
fac2 <- c(2,3,4,5,1,6)
fac3<- c(3,4,5,1,2,6)
fac4<- c(4,5,1,2,3, 6)
fac <- as.data.frame(cbind(fac1, fac2, fac3, fac4))
colnames(fac) <- c("station1", "station2", "station3", "station4")
rownames(fac) <- c("fac1", "fac2", "fac3", "fac4", "fac5", "fac6")
```

I imagine the result looking somewhat like this, somewhere keeping the names to know which combination is presented:

```
bac1-fac1 cor1 p1
bac1-fac2 cor2 p2
bac1-fac3 cor3 p3

bac2-fac1 corx px...
```

I have looked at function rcorr from Hmist and corr.test from psych, but can't find an example with the neccessary permutation of rows...Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you restructure your data, such that you compute correlation between paired columns, it would be super easy.

```
tbac <- data.frame(t(bac))
tfac <- data.frame(t(fac))

f <- function (x, y) cor(x, y)

tab <- outer(tfac, tbac, Vectorize(f))

as.data.frame.table(tab)
```

I had an answer using the same idea: [Match data and count number of same value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41683940/4891738).

Comment: Very compact way of doing this.  Great answer as always!

Comment: I didn't remember it, but thanks for sharing that one.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work very well! I was wondering why any correlation with fac6 produced NA, but figured it out (all values are 6).

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass the full matrices to the `cor` function (or `psych::corr.test`)and it takes care of finding the correlation of the relevant columns.

For example

```
cor(t(fac), t(bac))
#            bac1        bac2        bac3        bac4        bac5
# fac1  0.9899495 -0.07559289 -0.60000000 -0.60000000 -0.07559289
# fac2  0.9899495 -0.07559289 -0.60000000 -0.60000000 -0.07559289
# fac3 -0.3207135  0.94285714 -0.07559289 -0.07559289 -0.48571429
# fac4 -0.8000000 -0.32071349  0.98994949  0.98994949 -0.32071349
# fac5 -0.3207135 -0.48571429 -0.07559289 -0.07559289  0.94285714
# fac6         NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

You can then turn this in to long format using `reshape2::melt`

```
reshape2::melt(cor(t(fac), t(bac)))
#    Var1 Var2       value
# 1  fac1 bac1  0.98994949
# 2  fac2 bac1  0.98994949
# 3  fac3 bac1 -0.32071349
# 4  fac4 bac1 -0.80000000
# ---
# ---
```

To get the p-values use the same approach

```
test <- psych::corr.test(t(fac), t(bac), adjust="none")
```

And melt as before and join

```
merge(melt(test$r, value.name="cor"), melt(test$p, value.name="p-value"), by=c("Var1", "Var2"))
#   Var1 Var2         cor    p-value
# 1 fac1 bac1  0.98994949 0.01005051
# 2 fac1 bac2 -0.07559289 0.92440711
# 3 fac1 bac3 -0.60000000 0.40000000
# 4 fac1 bac4 -0.60000000 0.40000000
# 5 fac1 bac5 -0.07559289 0.92440711
# 6 fac2 bac1  0.98994949 0.01005051
```

Comment: That is a great option.  I missed the transpose part.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `expand.grid` to get the combinations of `rownames` of 'bac' and 'fac', loop through the rows with `apply` specifying the `MARGIN` as 1, subset the rows of 'bac' and 'fac' based on the rownames, do the `corr.test` and extract the 'p' values as a `list`

```
library(psych)
do.call(c, apply(expand.grid(rownames(bac), rownames(fac)), 1, 
  function(x) list(corr.test(cbind(unlist(bac[1,]), unlist(fac[1,])))$p)))
```

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi  It gets you some of the other parameters as welll in a `list`.  I think `rcorr` also does similar thing from `Hmisc`

Comment: I recently discovered expand.grid and I really liked it. But I try your solution, the output does not seem correct...and I don't have any row/columnnames?

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the rows of expand.grid

```
pairs <- as.matrix(expand.grid(1:nrow(bac),1:nrow(fac)))
pairs <- cbind(pairs,NA,NA)
b <- as.matrix(bac)
f <- as.matrix(fac)
for(i in 1:nrow(pairs)){
    pairs[i,3] <- cor(b[pairs[i,1],], f[pairs[i,2],])
    pairs[i,4] <- cor.test(b[pairs[i,1],], f[pairs[i,2],])$p.value
}
colnames(pairs) <- c('bac','fac','corr','p')
pairs
##      bac fac        corr          p
## [1,]   1   1  0.98994949 0.01005051
## [2,]   2   1 -0.07559289 0.92440711
## [3,]   3   1 -0.60000000 0.40000000
## [4,]   4   1 -0.60000000 0.40000000
## [5,]   5   1 -0.07559289 0.92440711
## [6,]   1   2  0.98994949 0.01005051
```

If you want the names you can then do

```
pairs <- as.data.frame(pairs)
pairs[,1] <- sapply(pairs[,1],function(x) rownames(bac)[x])
pairs[,2] <- sapply(pairs[,2],function(x) rownames(fac)[x])
```

although at that point it's probably easier to use 李哲源 Zheyuan Li 's solution.

Comment: Thanks, also very helpful, but does not keep the original names, which would be helpful in my "real" case!